# rosbridge (Websocket protocol update ?)

Tags: rosbridge

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everybody,
Did someone plan to update this package according the last websocket protocol ?

http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6455

Sincerely,

Benoît

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/31568/rosbridge-(websocket-protocol-update-?)/) by [BeuBeu](https://answers.ros.org/users/329/beubeu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 56 on 2012-04-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Are you sure you're running the latest version? A quick sanity check for me testing [this](http://pastebin.com/KZdiwUw2) webpage against [this](http://www.mediafire.com/?ic5jcln5n7vltgl) service works correctly under Firefox 11 for Windows, Firefox 11 for Fedora, Chrome 18 for Windows, and Chrome 18 for Fedora:

[os/browser sanity check](http://imagebin.org/208354)

---

Originally posted by [tjay](https://answers.ros.org/users/502/tjay/) with karma: 461 on 2012-04-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1